# Catalog search not working completely

Tags: php, magento

*I know this looks like a duplicate, but none of the solutions I found were solving my bug*

For example I have product with name "Baseball Caps" and SKU = 123456. When I search for "baseball" or "123456" I get results. But when I search for "base" or "1234" (just part of the name or the sku) then it does not work.

What I did:

1. checked for product quantity,visibility,price,availability and that the tested product belongs to category (not just the root one) and all seems to be good.
2. **System->Configuration->Catalog** and checked that in **Catalog Search** the Search Type field is **Like**. Also does not work with **Combined (Like and Fulltext)**
3. Cleared the Cache and did Re-Indexing
4. **Catalog->Manage Products->Update Attributes** for the Main website.

Still not working...

I really don't have any other ideas and I really need that.

I am using Enterprise 1.12.0.2

As suggested by *zhartaunik*, here is the query output that I get when I search with a query that works (for example `baseball`):

```
SELECT 1 AS 'status', 'e'.'entity_id', 'e'.'type_id', 'e'.'attribute_set_id', 'e'.'name', 'e'.'short_description', 'e'.'sku', 'e'.'price', 'e'.'special_price', 'e'.'special_from_date', 'e'.'special_to_date', 'e'.'small_image', 'e'.'thumbnail', 'e'.'color', 'e'.'color_value', 'e'.'news_from_date', 'e'.'news_to_date', 'e'.'url_key', 'e'.'required_options', 'e'.'image_label', 'e'.'small_image_label', 'e'.'thumbnail_label', 'e'.'msrp_enabled', 'e'.'msrp_display_actual_price_type', 'e'.'msrp', 'e'.'tax_class_id', 'e'.'price_type', 'e'.'weight_type', 'e'.'price_view', 'e'.'shipment_type', 'e'.'links_purchased_separately', 'e'.'links_exist', 'e'.'giftcard_amounts', 'e'.'allow_open_amount', 'e'.'open_amount_min', 'e'.'open_amount_max', 'e'.'customizable', 'e'.'is_cargo', 'e'.'minimum_quantity', 'e'.'super_price', 'e'.'label_sale', 'e'.'size', 'e'.'size_value', 'e'.'bestseller', 'e'.'favorite_present', 'e'.'manufacturer', 'e'.'manufacturer_value', 'e'.'favorite_present_position', 'e'.'sort', 'e'.'is_promoset', 'e'.'promoset_parts', 'e'.'promoset_product', 'e'.'promoset_options', 'e'.'promoset_benefits', 'e'.'is_firework', 'e'.'is_bulky', 'e'.'flavour', 'e'.'flavour_value', 'e'.'printed_order_number', 'e'.'ordernumber', 'e'.'customizableonly', 'search_result'.'relevance', 'price_index'.'price', 'price_index'.'tax_class_id', 'price_index'.'final_price', IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS 'minimal_price', 'price_index'.'min_price', 'price_index'.'max_price', 'price_index'.'tier_price', 'cat_index'.'position' AS 'cat_index_position' FROM 'catalog_product_flat_4' AS 'e'
 INNER JOIN 'catalogsearch_result' AS 'search_result' ON search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id='188'
 INNER JOIN 'catalog_product_index_price' AS 'price_index' ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '2' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN 'catalog_category_product_index' AS 'cat_index' ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='4' AND cat_index.visibility IN(3, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='92' ORDER BY 'relevance' desc LIMIT 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Please insert into file:

> for default 1.9 magento
>
> \app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml
>
> else please put the name of your theme and your package instead
>   rwd\default

after row $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

following code:

```
Mage::log($_productCollection->getSelectSQL(1), false, 'search-query.log', true);
```

Run search and copy from the file /var/log/search-query.log your query.

Comment: It does not generate the 'search-query.log'` if I search with `base` (a non-existing-word query). It generates it, though, when I search with `baseball` (and in that case the search works).